# PHP slugifying HTML entity code backwards R

Tags: php

I'm trying to create some clean URLs for artist names.  I'm using the following to parse Pearl Jam to pearl-jam.  All is fine until it tries to process KoЯn.  Instead of returning korn, it is returning koand1071n.  In my database, KoЯn is actually stored as

> `Ko&#1071;n`

I'm using this code below.  What can I do to handle the backwards R?

```
$delimiter = "-";
$clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
$clean = str_replace("\$", "s", $clean); 
$clean = preg_replace( '/&/', 'and', $clean );
$clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
$clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
$clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);
$clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
```

Comment: Why do you not want to respect the band's choice of name? :P

Comment: I think you just need a special case for it. But you might want to unescape your entities first?

Comment: `Ko&#1071;n` - isn't utf-8, it's pretty ASCII-safe string

Comment: PS: `Я` wouldn't be transliterated to `R`, it's completely different letter. Mirroring doesn't make them similar - see at p & q, d & b

Comment: For SEO, no one types in KoЯn when searching.  They type it in as Korn.. so I'd like to handle accordingly.

Comment: @zerkms - assuming the OP's constraint of slugifying to ASCII, what would be the best letter to convert it to?

Comment: @halfer: in this particular case - to `R`, but it's not a general rule to convert Cyrillic `Я` to `R`, since it's pronounced like `ya` (like the first vovel in New York *Yankees*). So treat KOЯN -> KORN as an exception in transliteration

Comment: Can you fix your database?  Having HTML in places where you don't allow HTML is going to be a nightmare for you later on, if it isn't already.  Otherwise, you are going to have to post-convert every time you want to use that data in another context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace Я with a r with str_replace like you do for $

```
$clean = str_replace("Я", "r", $clean);
```

or

```
$clean = str_replace("&#1071;", "r", $clean);
```